# http keep-alive timeout on server

Tags: http-headers, go, keep-alive, httpconnection

Does the Go server have an `http` keep-alive default timeout value?

How do you set a custom keep-alive timeout?

Is the server's `ReadTimeout` related to the keep-alive timeout at all? or you need to set the keep-alive timeout directly in the `http` response header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This issue](https://codereview.appspot.com/7220076) shows they made the ReadTimeout server setting be per-request not per connection. This is the value you are looking to set to timeout keep-alives.

Comment: Doesn't look like Go has a specific timeout value you can set. I know there are OS specific TCP timeouts that will close your connection if no data is passed.

Comment: Do you have any specific suggestions for Linux servers?

Comment: A quick google shows: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-increasing-or-decreasing-tcp-sockets-timeouts.html

You could also maybe run a goroutine that watches for old/stale connections.

Comment: wow, keep-alive defaults to 2 hours... probably setting the server's ReadTimeout on the request might be the best solution for the meantime

Comment: Looks like this was reported before: https://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=4676

However it looks like they fixed it: https://codereview.appspot.com/7220076 which says "Deadlines should be extended at the beginning of
a request, not at the beginning of a connection."

Comment: Thanks Ben for spotting this. So, if this is implemented properly, I think it's a good enough mechanism (although not exactly as the keep-alive) to limit the lifetime of a connection.

Comment: I updated my original answer with the info from the code review which shows they made the ReadTimeout per request and not per connection which should be exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Ben, I think the first part of the answer is confusing. I would just focus on the second part.